# Arithmetic operation in Dart+Polymer throws an invalid argument exception

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I encountered an odd problem with Dart 1.16.0 + Polymer. To perform calculation, the double type input parameter need to be converted to string and then back again to double for computation, otherwise an invalid argument exception will be thrown. Could anyone point out where I might have gone wrong?

HTML code, **stats.html**

```
        <div class="container flex-horizontal">
            <div class="flexchild-horizontal">
                <div class="container flex-horizontal">
                    <div class="flexchild-horizontal">Base</div>
                    <div><input type="text" name="base" value="{{base::input}}" size="5" maxlength="5"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flexchild-horizontal">
                <div class="container flex-horizontal">
                    <div class="flexchild-horizontal">Calculated Value</div>
                    <div><input type="text" name="calc_value" value="{{calculateValue(base)}}" size="5" maxlength="5"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Dart code, **stats.dart**

```
@HtmlImport('stats.html')
library workbench.lib.client.stats;

import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart' show HtmlImport;
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_material.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_styles.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/iron_flex_layout.dart';

@PolymerRegister('stats')
class Stats extends PolymerElement {

  @property(notify: true)
  double base = 10.0;

  //@Property(computed: 'calculateValue(base)')
  //double value;

  Stats.created() : super.created();

  @reflectable
  double calculateValue(double b) {
    print("Base is ");
    print(b);

    // Not working. Throw an invalid Argument: 5.0 Exception
    // var c = b + 5.0;

    // Working
    var c = double.parse(b.toString()) + 5.0;
    print("c is ");
    print(c);

    return c;
  }

  ready() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to use `num` instead of `double`.
At least in Dartium as far as I know `5.0` would be returned as `int`, not as `double`. This is because in JS there is no distinction between `int` and `double` possible.

Proper distinction between `int` and `double` is only working on the server (standalone VM). It also works in Dartium as long as the value is not passed from JS.

Comment: The exception is thrown on the arithmetic operation

Comment: Same problem after changing to num. Also the code is run in Dartium without conversion to JS. So it is purely just Dart.

Comment: If it interacts with Polymer it is not purely just Dart. Polymer is purely JS and only wrapped by Dart code that forwards to JS.

Comment: That explains the odd behavior. Even though the Dart function is specified as taking in double as input parameters. Noticed that the actual data that get passed into the Dart function can be arbitrary type. This problem only surface during run-time. Would you recommend using String data type as a safer option?

Comment: I would need to debug it to be sure. At first I would try `num` instead of `double`. If you get `String` passed, it might be a bug. The `<input>` element returns `String` AFAIK (even if it is `type="number"`. If you get the value from there, then I'd use `String` as type and parse it.

Comment: Changed double to num type. Same problem.  For calculateValue(num b) function, it does not matter what type b parameter is. Even String gets through. Can get the value using num.parse(b.toString()) but not b directly.

Comment: `calculateValue(base)` should pass a `num` not a `String`. If it doesn't I'd consider it a bug in Polymer.dart.